# change the background of div when the link is clicked and change this back to previous one when another link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

change the background of div when the link is clicked and change this back to previous one when another link is clicked...

```
    <div class="home" id="home"><span style="position: relative;top:9px;"><a href="index.php"><img src="home.png" width="20%" align="bottom" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></span></div> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="profile" id="profile" ><span style="position: relative;top:9px;"><a href="profile.php"><img src="home.png" width="20%" align="bottom" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Profile</a></span></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

when i click on home it's background should change to some other color so that it gives the look of what page is in user...

Comment: whenever a user clicks on your link a full page load is occurring ? 
and you want the newly loaded page to retain a specific background color, instead of applying the background color to the links on current page? 

Please correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: yes thats what i want..how can i do that..??

Comment: Have a look at the answer I have provided below.

Answer (score 0):

This is considering if the original background of `.home` is blue.

```
$('.home').click(function() {
    $(this).css({background: 'red'});
});

$('.profile').click(function() {
   $('.home').css({background: 'blue'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
 .active{
 background:url(yourimage_url);
}
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var pageTitle = window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*\/([^/]*)/, "$1");
            $('.active').removeClass("active");
            ///// Apply active class to selected page link
            $('.menu a').each(function () {

                if ($(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() == pageTitle.toLocaleLowerCase())
                    $(this).closest('div').addClass('active');
            });
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="menu">
     <div class="home" id="home"><span style="position: relative;top:9px;"><a href="index.php"><img src="home.png" width="20%" align="bottom" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></span></div> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="profile" id="profile" ><span style="position: relative;top:9px;"><a href="profile.php"><img src="home.png" width="20%" align="bottom" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Profile</a>
    </span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this . It remove class 'active' and set active class for that particular current div

```
<style>

.active { background : blue; }

</style>

$("div").on("click" , function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).attr('id').addClass("active");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it the other way around, you might have to change href paths in your markup from relative (i.e. index.php) to root paths (i.e. /index.php) to make this work.

### Markup

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="home" id="home"><span style="position: relative;top:9px;"><a href="/index.php"><img src="home.png" width="20%" align="bottom" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></span></div> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="profile" id="profile" ><span style="position: relative;top:9px;"><a href="/profile.php"><img src="home.png" width="20%" align="bottom" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Profile</a></span></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

### Script

```
$(function(){
    $(".nav a").each(function(){
        var $item = $(this);
        if($item.attr('href') == window.location.pathname){
            $item.css("background", "#FF0000").addClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the path in hyperlink tag and do you have jquery included in your page ?